# Python, TypeError: missing positional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I've tried all kinds of things and I have no clue what I am doing wrong. After trying about 5 different ways of doing this I gave in to asking for help on here. What am I doing wrong?

```
#tried to do this all sorts of ways but gave up
#someone please tell me what the heck I'm doing wrong here

CONSTANT_COUNTY_TAX = 0.02

CONSTANT_STATE_TAX = 0.04

def intro(monthSales):
    print ("This program shows how many taxes you will have to pay on your sales")

def sales():   
    monthSales = eval(input("Enter the total of sales of this month: "))
    return monthSales

def calcCountyTax(sales):
    sales(monthSales)
    countyTaxDue = sales*CONSTANT_COUNTY_TAX
    return countyTaxDue

def calcStateTax(sales):
    sales(monthSales)
    stateTaxDue = sales*CONSTANT_STATE_TAX
    return stateTaxDue

def total(stateTaxDue, countyTaxDue, monthlSales):
    sales(monthSales)
    calcStateTax(monthSales)
    calcCountyTax(monthSales)
    totalSum = sales - (stateTaxDue + countyTaxDue)
    return totalSum


def main():
    intro()
    sales()
    calcStateTax(monthSales)
    calcCountyTax(monthSales)
    total(monthSales, stateTAxDue, countyTaxDue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here:

- You define `intro` as taking a parameter `monthSales` but in `main` you call it with no argument.
- In `sales` you are using `eval` where you don't really need to. Try something like this instead:

  ```
  def sales():   
      monthSales = int(input("Enter the total of sales of this month: "))
      return monthSales
  ```
- In `calcCountyTax` you are taking a paramater named `sales` and then treating it as if it is a function itself. You can use functions as parameters but it probably isn't what you intend here. Perhaps something more like:

  ```
  def calcCountyTax(sales):
      countyTaxDue = sales * CONSTANT_COUNTY_TAX
      return countyTaxDue
  ```
- Same issue with `calcStateTax`
- The `monthlSales` parameter to `total` is a typo, should be `monthSales`.
- If you are passing precalculated `stateTaxDue` and `countyTaxDue` into the `total` function, you don't need to recalculate the amount of tax due. The `total` function can be simplified:

  ```
  def total(monthSales, stateTaxDue, countyTaxDue):
      totalSum = sales - (stateTaxDue + countyTaxDue)
      return totalSum
  ```
- In your `main` method you aren't storing the values returned from the functions as you call them. `main` should look more like this:

  ```
  def main():
      intro()
      monthlySales = sales()
      monthlyStateTax = calcStateTax(monthlySales)
      monthlyCountyTax = calcCountyTax(monthlySales)
      afterTax = total(monthlySales, monthlyStateTax, monthlyCountyTax)
      print(afterTax)
  ```
- You never call the `main` function. If you just define it but never call it, nothing will happen when you run the script. At the bottom of your script after the definition of `main`, add:

  ```
  def main():
      intro()
      monthlySales = sales()
      ...
      print(afterTax)

  main()
  ```

There are a few other stylistic things (Python names are usually of the form `county_tax_due` instead of the camel-cased `countyTaxDue`, for instance), but I've tried to focus specifically on why your script isn't working without making other major changes.

Comment: you sure got me a lot closer tot he answer but I am still getting a nasty error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karlmachleidt/Desktop/Lab 2.7.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/karlmachleidt/Desktop/Lab 2.7.py", line 36, in main
    afterTax = total(monthlySales, monthlyStateTax, monthlyCountyTax)
  File "/Users/karlmachleidt/Desktop/Lab 2.7.py", line 27, in total
    totalSum = sales - (stateTaxDue + countyTaxDue)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'float'

Comment: I figured it out, but now I am getting -10.2.. if my input is 10 i don't really know how , I changed the total(monthSales...) to total(sales...)

Comment: I got it , i mixed up the order of input thanks for your help, mate

Answer (score 0):

You defined `def intro(monthSales):` but you are calling it without parameter `intro()` in `main()`.

Similarly, here you are calling sales function with parameter

```
def calcStateTax(sales):
sales(monthSales) #
```

but it is the function doesn't accept any parameters.

```
def sales():
```

Also, you are using `monthSales` variables in different functions but it is not defined as global. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) link will help you understand various scopes of python variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since the others have done you the favor of reviewing your code, here's an approach that's intentionally overkill but is a somewhat more appealing way of going about with a simple calculation problem.

```
class Tax(object):

    COUNTY = 0.02
    STATE = 0.04

    def __init__(self, sales):
        self.__sales = sales

    @property
    def calc_statedue(self):
        return self.STATE * self.__sales

    @property
    def calc_countydue(self):
        return self.COUNTY * self.__sales

    @property
    def calc_totaldue(self):
        return self.calc_countydue + self.calc_statedue

    @property
    def calc_taxfree_profit(self):
        return self.__sales - self.calc_totaldue


def main():

    print "This program shows how much tax you will need to pay on your sales."
    sales = float(raw_input("Enter the total sales for this month:\n>> "))
    # You can add a check here to see if sales is not non-numerical, perhaps
    # an isdigit, isalpha, float, type, etc. check. Your call.

    tax_calc = Tax(sales)
    print "Taxes due to county: ", tax_calc.calc_countydue
    print "Taxes due to state: ", tax_calc.calc_statedue    
    print "Total taxes due: ", tax_calc.calc_totaldue
    print "Profit after taxes: ", tax_calc.calc_taxfree_profit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
In [6]: runfile('C:/Users/.../.spyder2/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/.../.spyder2')
This program shows how much tax you will need to pay on your sales.

Enter the total sales for this month:
>> 1200
Taxes due to county:  24.0
Taxes due to state:  48.0
Total taxes due:  72.0
Profit after taxes:  1128.0

In [7]:
```

Comment: I like your answer but sadly this is for a college assignment and I would not be able to explain this, since I am pretty new to Python